# Is there a way to live update the page when using p5js?

Tags: javascript, processing, sublimetext3, p5.js

I was wondering if there is a way to update the html page on-the-go without having to refresh the browser. Looking for something similar to LiveReload or LiveStyle.

Toolset: p5js on Sublime Text 3 + chrome

Cheers,
öz

Comment: Like real time updates? SignalR might be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [BrowserSync](https://browsersync.io/) for this, doesn't matter if you're using p5 or not.

You need [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) for this. You can install BrowserSync using the command :

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

Then browse to your project directory and open browsersync using :

```
browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*"
```

This will open a new tab in your browser which will list files in the directory, you can then select a html file to load and you should see a **Connected to Browsersync** message on the top right.
This will also track changes in all files in your current directory and update the page whenever any file changes.